# Referencing a variable in REPLACE INTO throws a sqlite3.OperationalError

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

My a script processes entries in an SQLite3 table and makes a series of changes. Last step is to write out a table summarising which folders on disk will be affected by the changes (the changes are independently written back to the underlying files in the filesystem).

```
dbcursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT __dirpath FROM alib where sqlmodded > 0')
dirpaths = dbcursor.fetchall()
dirpaths.sort()
dbcursor.execute('create table IF NOT EXISTS dirs_to_process (__dirpath blob PRIMARY KEY);')
for dirpath in dirpaths:
    dirpathstring = dirpath[0]
    dbcursor.execute(f"REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES {dirpathstring}")
```

The last line of code throws an error:

> dbcursor.execute(f"REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES {dirpathstring}")
> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "/": syntax error

I've tried:

```
dbcursor.execute("REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES (?)", (dirpathstring))
```

But am not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
dbcursor = connection.cursor()

dbcursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT __dirpath FROM alib')
dirpaths = dbcursor.fetchall()
dirpaths.sort()

dbcursor.execute('create table IF NOT EXISTS dirs_to_process (__dirpath blob PRIMARY KEY);')

for dirpath in dirpaths:
    dirpathstring = dirpath[0]
    print(f'{dirpath} => {dirpathstring}')
    dbcursor.execute(f"REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES (?)", (dirpathstring,))

connection.commit()
print('Done')
```

Notice how the `replace` command is run. The query will be:

```
replace into table (column) values (?)
```

We'll feed a `set` to the execute command after the query like so:

```
('/dir1',)
```

At the end, we'll commit the data so that the data gets saved in the DB.

I had inserted in alib the following data:

- /dir1
- /dir1/dir2
- /dir1/dir3/

When I run `python3 test.py`, I will get the following output:

python3 test.py
('/dir1',) => /dir1
('/dir1/dir2',) => /dir1/dir2
('/dir1/dir3/',) => /dir1/dir3/

When I query SQLite using `sqlite3 test.db` and run:

```
sqlite> select * from dirs_to_process;

-- I get the following output
/dir1
/dir1/dir2
/dir1/dir3/
```

Hope this helps. Give it a try.

---

Just know that you could even do like this:

```
for dirpath in dirpaths:
    dbcursor.execute(f"REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES (?)", dirpath)
```

and eliminate the need for `dirpathstring = dirpath[0]`, unless you absolutely need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
dbcursor.execute('SELECT DISTINCT __dirpath FROM alib where sqlmodded > 0')
dirpaths = dbcursor.fetchall()
dirpaths.sort()
dbcursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dirs_to_process (__dirpath blob PRIMARY KEY);')
for dirpath in dirpaths:

    record = (f'REPLACE INTO dirs_to_process (__dirpath) VALUES ("{dirpath[0]}")')
    dbcursor.execute(record)
```

Comment: If `__dirpath` in alib contains `"` or `'`, then your query may begin failing again. Therefore, parameterized inserts are a safe way to store data. I have an example in my answer. With parameterization, you won't have to worry about special characters causing failure in your query.